# Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder in MultiBlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In Flutter I am using bloc and have a special case where is MultiBlocProvider and I need to provide context to widget which is below it.

This is code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext **context**) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<LoginCubit>(create: (_) => LoginCubit()),
          BlocProvider<UserDetailBloc>(
            create: (_) => UserDetailBloc(UserRepository())..add(UserLogged()),
          ),
        ],
        child: BlocBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
```

Problem is that I am providing the context in bold, what is wrong and it is necessary to provide context below MultiBlocProvider, but I do not know how to declare it in code.
There is an example how to do it:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
```

But I am not able to find how do declare it with MultiBlocProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example to use better way MultiBlocProvider

```
MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider<BlocA>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(),
    ),
    BlocProvider<BlocB>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => BlocB(),
    ),
    BlocProvider<BlocC>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => BlocC(),
    ),
  ],
  child: ChildA(),
)

class ChildA extends StatelessWidget {
  ChildA({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold()
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the type like so

```dart
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
  // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

**Example** for your case, if you want the `LoginCubit` pass the cubit & state after the `BlockBuilder` between the angle brackets <>.

```dart
// this
 child: BlocBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(

// should look like this
 child: BlocBuilder<LoginCubit, LoginState>(builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
```